# Parallel Cucumber Report

Tags: ruby, cucumber, parallel-testing

I'm trying to get Parallel_Cucumber to save a report once my tests are complete.  I've followed the docs and added the following to my cucumber.yml:

```
parallel:   --format html --out report<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER']%>.html
```

I'm getting no report from it.

Is there something I'm missing.  Do I need to add something to my command line when running the test? So far I'm using:

```
parallel_cucumber features/ -n 8 -o "-r features"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not running the `parallel` profile added to cucumber.yml. Add `-p parallel` to your command as:

`parallel_cucumber features/ -n 8 -o "-r features" -p parallel`

Comment: I had realised a little later on, such a rookie mistake!!! Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: are you aware of the HTML reports causing the Cucumber tests to fail? I get lots of erros such as field id's can't be found etc, but I change the format of the report and it works fine? It appears to be on all tests that have a puts command

Comment: None that I am aware of, but if you find a consistent failure example you could raise an issue on their github repo.